# Pass JavaScript variable into vue component on the root element

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to pass a dynamic javascript variable(an **ionRangeSlider()** value) into an external Vue component in my `#app` element. but the variable is outside the `#app` element and I keep getting this error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "range" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

I tried to define it on the instance by giving it a default value as follows:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {'range': [0,2000]}, // Default value
});
```

And it gets the value in the component but it doesn't get the new changed value since it is not getting it from the main file where the **.ionRangeSlider()** is instantiated and listening from.

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="page-content">
            <filterables 
                    :range="range">
            </filterables>
    </div>  
</div>

<script>
        var range = [];
        $("#b_range").ionRangeSlider({

          type:"double",grid:!0,min:0,max:4e3,from:0,to:2e3,prefix:"$",
          onFinish: function (data) {

            let minRange = data.from;
            let maxRange = data.to;

            range = [minRange ,maxRange ];
            console.log(range);

          }
        });
</script>
```

I am kinda new to Vue, I wanted to know how I can pass the **range** value to the **filterable** component. any help is appreciated!